# Python def function

Tags: python, function

My issue is that when trying to use the 'def' keyword I end up with a traceback that says:

```
"nameError: name 'a' is not defined".
```

If anyone could explain this error, I would appreciate it.

Edit: thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think you understand how parameters work; perhaps you should run through a structured tutorial?

Comment: You are mixing the function parameters with local variables of that function.

Comment: What do you expect `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` to be?

Comment: Notice that when you call `score = computegrade( a, b, c, d, e )` none of those variables exist. The `a`, `b`, and etc... that you define are local to the function and only exist within that function and only when the function is being run. In fact, if you called the function in multiple threads, multiple independent versions of the variables would exist.

Comment: I agree with Jon, you should read a tutorial http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens on the line

```
score = computegrade(a, b, c, d, e)
```

because it refers to 5 variables named `a` .. `e`, which have not been defined yet (they haven't been assigned values in the global scope). However, to me that your expectation is that they'd get their values from within the function, which is not true in Python; what goes within the parentheses are just the inputs to the function.

---

I believe that your `computegrade` function should be an algorithm that has one input (one argument) - the score; and one output - the grade that corresponds to that score. Within the function, you would return the score as a 1-character **string** corresponding to each score bracket:

```
def computegrade(score): 
    if score >= 0.9:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 0.8:
        return "B"
    # ...
    else:
        return "E"
```

Then you can use this function as

```
score = raw_input ("Please enter your score:")
score = float(score)
grade = computegrade(score)
print "Your grade is", grade
```

Comment: @Ninjaheman ah I just mean that your `computegrade` would need just 1 input - the `score`.

Comment: "what do I need to calculate my pay" - "hours and hourly rate". for grade, you'd need the score right? What would you do with your hourly rate?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are basically what you 'give' the function so that it can do it's work. In this case the function needs one thing - the score that the user entered. It then takes that score and using if statements, decides what grade it is and returns it. In this case your function doesn't need to know what `a, b, c, d, e` is. @Antti Haapala gave good code. Returning something is what gives value to the function. When you say `score = computegrade(score)`, it gives `score` to the function and then sets score equal to whatever you return. Antti Haapala's code works because you don't need the redundant print statements. In other words, you print `A` in the function, and then the function sets `score` equal to `A`, and then prints `score`.